# Datepicker ui-bootstrap setting value from model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the ui-bootstrap datepicker for my angular form. When I get the json from the database and set the value on the form the Date shows on the input but I can't submit because the input does not recognise the value from the scope, and I have to pick again the dates. I'll explain better:

This is my datepicker options in the controller that I copied from the documentation:

```
$scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
  $scope.today();

  $scope.clear = function() {
    $scope.dt = null;
  };

  $scope.open = function( $event ) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.open2 = function( $event ) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened2 = true;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
  };

  $scope.formats = [ 'dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate' ];
  $scope.format = $scope.formats[ 0 ];
```

My edit input is like this:

```
<div class="input-group"><input name="StartDate" type="text" class="form-control" popup-placement="top-left" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" is-open="opened" close-text="Close" ng-model="period.StartDate" id="StartDate" required />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default calendar-input" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
          </span></div>
```

For debug purpose I showed the `$scope.period.StarDate` and at the beginning the date shows without quotes, but if choose again on the picker it shows with quotes.

What I tried was to filter the data before show it on the view like this:

```
$scope.period.StartDate = $filter('date')($scope.period.StartDate, 'dd-MMMM-yyyy');
```

The date is show it fine on the input and does let me submit it, but it saves only 0000-00-00 on the database. How do I filter the date from the json for the datepicker can recognize the data?

UPDATE

The data Type on the database is "date" only, and when I do the query the json brings the date like this: 2017-07-30T00:00:00.000Z

Even if I don't put required on the datepicker, it expect a date before doing the submit.

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle to illustrate your problem

Comment: I tried, but can't represent the problem manually :(

Comment: You need to convert it to date. $scope.period.StartDate = new Date(yourJsonField)

Comment: @yBrodsky nice! that worked. Thanks!

Comment: When you say `when I do the query the json brings the date like this: 2017-07-30T00:00:00.000Z`. Do you mean this date comes from DB in such a manner...

Comment: I guess your problem is that you are binding the value of a filter to the date input model, which expects a date object while filter's output would be `string`. I am not sure if it should even display it on screen with `string`. But as you said it is displaying, probably its causing a issue while you submit the `string` and it is parsed as a `date`.

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari On database is save it like 2017-07-20, I'm guessing the reason that comes on the json like that is beacause of Sequelize. But the answer that gave me yBrodsky was the solution